# CMake use specific Boost version

Tags: boost, cmake

I am working on a project where I am linking against a library which was itself linked against `boost 1.48`. I am looking for a way to specify in my `CMakeLists.txt` that I want the system to find and only use the boost 1.48 library.

I am not able to update the version the other library was compiled against and so I cannot set a **minimum** version number I need a way to set the **only** acceptable boost version. I have not been able to find a method to do this.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html):

format is as follows:

```
 find_package(package version EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS components…)
```

so if you need exactly 1.48 then you should use (example):

```
 find_package(Boost 1.48 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread date_time)
```